# Angularjs. Jsonp. Sending data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp

I try to send data using JSONP request in AngularJS.

```
$http({ method: 'jsonp', 
url: 'http://test.local/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK',  /// Add '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
data: JSON.stringify(request) })
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) { });
```

Is this possible?

Comment: in angularjs document they have provided the JSONP sample, that may helpful. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#methods_jsonp

Answer (score 9):

Yes it's possible see the [$http.jsonp function](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#jsonp). In short you should do something like

```
$http.jsonp('http://www.example.com?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
  .success (function(data, ...) {
    //your data here
    ...
  })
```

Please be aware that you must set **callback=JSON_CALLBACK** as a query parameter of your http call in order for angular to do its magic.

To send data along with your request it will depend if you want query parameters (1), request message data (2) or both (3).

Case 1 :

```
$http.jsonp('http://www.example.com?callback=JSON_CALLBACK', {params : Object | String})
```

as per documentation "Map of strings or objects which will be turned to ?key1=value1&key2=value2 after the url. If the value is not a string, it will be JSONified."

Case 2 :

```
$http.jsonp('http://www.example.com?callback=JSON_CALLBACK', {data : Object | String})
```

Case 3 :

```
$http.jsonp('http://www.example.com?callback=JSON_CALLBACK', {params : Object | String, data : Object | String})
```

Comment: problem is in sending data, not in handling recieved answer

Comment: I use angular 1.0.7 and Case 2 don't work. Chrome don't send any data. (

Comment: Please read the question before answer it. There is no relation between your answer and the OP question.

Comment: ["You can no longer use the `JSON_CALLBACK` string as a placeholder for specifying where the callback parameter value should go"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp). Use this instead: `$http.jsonp('some/trusted/url', {jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'})`

Answer (score 6):

Late answer, but: `data` only works for `POST` requests. However you can't make a `POST` request with JSONP -- the way it works is it inserts a `<script>` tag into your DOM with `src` set to the URL of the request; when your browser evaluates the script it will call the callback parameter (Angular basically replaces `JSON_CALLBACK` by a pointer to your success function).

TL;DR: the only way you can send stuff to the server using JSONP is using the `params` key in the config.

Comment: ["You can no longer use the `JSON_CALLBACK` string as a placeholder for specifying where the callback parameter value should go"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp). Use this instead: `$http.jsonp('some/trusted/url', {jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'})`