# how to access angularjs callback result jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I have a WMS query with url like this.

http://giswebservices.massgis.state.ma.us/geoserver/wms?VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&LAYERS=massgis:GISDATA.ACECS_POLY&SRS=EPSG:26986&BBOX=11830.0,776202.9449152543,348201.0,961492.0550847457&WIDTH=708&HEIGHT=390&INFO_FORMAT=text/javascript&FEATURE_COUNT=10&QUERY_LAYERS=massgis:GISDATA.ACECS_POLY&X=120&Y=109&FORMAT&STYLES=&SERVICE=WMS

This url returns JSON result `parseResponse( ...json...)`

I want to create angularjs $http jsonp but it did not work.

```
function appCtrl($scope, $http){
    function parseResponse(data) {
        $scope.data = data
    } 

    var httpOptions = {
        url: "http://giswebservices.massgis.state.ma.us/geoserver/wms?VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=massgis:GISDATA.ACECS_POLY&SRS=EPSG:26986&BBOX=11830.0,776202.9449152543,348201.0,961492.0550847457&WIDTH=708&HEIGHT=390&INFO_FORMAT=text/javascript&FEATURE_COUNT=10&QUERY_LAYERS=massgis:GISDATA.ACECS_POLY&X=120&Y=109&FORMAT&STYLES=&SERVICE=WMS",
        method: "JSONP",
        params : {
            REQUEST: 'GetFeatureInfo',
        },
    };

    $http(httpOptions).
        success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $scope.data = data;
        }).
        error(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
}
```

This gives error "**parseResponse is not defined**" But I defined that function

Comment: Are you trying to do an http.get? Or how I'm interpreting, trying to ping a server and getting a json back?

Comment: I don't think you should modify your question to an entirely new question, else my answer doesn't make sense. Can you revert and ask a new question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try set **format_options** in params, Because angularjs default callback function name is **JSON_CALLBACK**

```
var httpOptions = {
    url: "http://giswebservices.massgis.state.ma.us/geoserver/wms?VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=massgis:GISDATA.ACECS_POLY&SRS=EPSG:26986&BBOX=11830.0,776202.9449152543,348201.0,961492.0550847457&WIDTH=708&HEIGHT=390&INFO_FORMAT=text/javascript&FEATURE_COUNT=10&QUERY_LAYERS=massgis:GISDATA.ACECS_POLY&X=120&Y=109&FORMAT&STYLES=&SERVICE=WMS",
    method: "JSONP",
    params : {
        REQUEST: 'GetFeatureInfo',
        format_options: 'callback: JSON_CALLBACK'
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to access your AngularJS callback result using `jsonp`:

http://jsfiddle.net/jCUSh/138/

```
function WMSCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.nums = [1,2,3]
    $scope.data = null;
    $scope.get_data = function() {
      var url2 = 'http://giswebservices.massgis.state.ma.us/geoserver/wms?VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=massgis:GISDATA.ACECS_POLY&SRS=EPSG:26986&BBOX=11830.0,776202.9449152543,348201.0,961492.0550847457&WIDTH=708&HEIGHT=390&INFO_FORMAT=text/javascript&FEATURE_COUNT=10&QUERY_LAYERS=massgis:GISDATA.ACECS_POLY&X=120&Y=109&FORMAT&STYLES=&SERVICE=WMS'
      $http.jsonp(url2, {params : {REQUEST: 'GetFeatureInfo'}});
    }

    window.parseResponse = function(data) {
      $scope.data = data
    }
}
```

I took off a vital param on the url (which was `REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo`) and included it in the params argument on the `jsonp` function call to show an example of how the `params` arguments is passed.

Comment: how can I separate query string as json parameters and send

Comment: and why did you defined window.parseResponse?

Comment: Actually, here's a post that show's how you specify params in a jsonp call
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676085/angularjs-jsonp-sending-data

Comment: And I defined window.parseResponse to deliver the data out of the JSON callback, since it's wrapped in a parseResponse function. I assumed you just wanted the JSON?

Comment: Your solution is great, I tried this http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/Wqu68/ but can not catch callback and success function did not work

Comment: If the solution was correct, could you also mark it as correct? I wouldn't mind debugging more of your code

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle that works: you must declare parseResponse as a window function. http://jsfiddle.net/Wqu68/2/